# catch variable in ajax success function to stop submit form

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have a problem within this code.
I want to choose whether I will submit the 
form or not based on the outcome off the ajaxcall.

If I hardcode it with return false; It stops going to the paypal site.
That's why I want it to depend on a variable set in the ajax succes function.

It is probably lost in the callback, so that's why I ask for help.

This is the code:

```
$("#img_download").click(function(e){

    $("#main_content").find('span').not('#loading').remove();
    loading.fadeIn(1000);
    $("#main_content").load("../../../includes/snip.php #betaalbox", function(){
        var invoerGebruikersnaam = $("#gebruikersnaam");
        var invoerEmail = $("#email");
        loading.hide();

        if($("#uitloggentaxibel").size()!=0){
            //alert('we zijn ingelogd');
            $('#idgebruikerbox').hide();
            ingelogd=1;
        }else{
            invoerEmail.focus();
            //alert('we zijn niet ingelogd');
        }

         $('form#paypalio').submit(function(){ 
            if(invoerGebruikersnaam.attr("value") && invoerEmail.attr("value")){
                alert('is gecheckt, check ook op geldig emailadres');
                //check ook voor een geldig emailadres
                //OK, dan...
                //vergelijk met db gegevens
                gebruikersnaam = invoerGebruikersnaam.attr("value");
                email = invoerEmail.attr("value");
                $.ajax({
                url: "/includes/pdt_paypal.php",
                data: ({gebruikersnaam: gebruikersnaam, actie: "idgebruikercheck", email: email}),
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data,textStatus){
                //$('#main_content').html(data.responseText);
                //sla geretourneerde gegevens bij gebruiker op
                identificatie=data.check;
                if(identificatie=="ok"){
                    customstring=email;

                    $('.bericht.idgebruikerfout').html('identificatie was ok').show();
                }else{
                    $('.bericht.idgebruikerfout').html('identificatie heeft gefaald').show();
                    annuleerPayPal="ok";
                }

                }//EINDE success
                    ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        if(textStatus == 'timeout') {
                            //doe iets
                        }else if (textStatus == 'error'){
                            //doe iets
                        } 
                    }//EINDE error

                });//EINDE ajax
                //ZOJA, dan...

             }else{

                $('.bericht.idgebruikerfout').html(idfout2).show();
                return false;
             }
             if(annuleerPayPal=="ok"){return false;}     

                //return false;     
        });//EINDE submit
    });//EINDE load

});
```

**EDIT BECAUSE**

I solved it by removing the logic off setting a variable, because it get's lost.
My best guess is that the different callbacks return to a different context.

Anyway, by being a bit more direct, by evaluating an if/else statement block within one context(callback), I simply Instruct to submit the form.
$('form').submit();

**solved**

thanks, Richard

Comment: And do you ever plan to accept any answers folks provide? No pressure, I just won't waste my time checking the outcome of the question if I know you won't accept anybodies answer regardless.

Comment: I don't know what you are saying, whatever does that mean I don't want to put this in a bad way, but what is it that you want to pressure me fore???By the way, thanks for the solution. I must have been staring to my code for to long that I couldn't see it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Add this somewhere around the top:

```
  var SubmitForm = false;
```

Then add this after it pass validation:

```
if(identificatie=="ok"){
       SubmitForm = true;  //<--- this part
       customstring=email;
```

Then return that variable instead of returning flat true or false;

```
   return SubmitForm;
```

Quick edit:

I assumed you want to submit the form based on what the ajax request *returned*, not on wheter it was simply successful. The same idea applies, you just need to add the:

```
       SubmitForm = true;
```

Before the `if(identificatie=="ok"){` instead of after, so that it gets turned to true right after the request is a known success.